# how to create a function to set or get style property value?

Tags: javascript, this

i write a function want to set or get style property value:

```
function $(ID){return document.getElementById(ID);}

Object.prototype.css=function(style,value){
    if(value==undefined){
        return eval("this.style."+style);
    }
    else{
        if(isNaN(value)){
            return eval("this.style."+style+"=\""+value+"\"");
        }
        else{
            return eval("this.style."+style+"="+value);
        }
    }
}

function ad(){
    $("ad_ol").css("top","-170px");
}
```

it can work well in FireFox 、 Chrome and IE9,but not work in IE7 and IE8,error message is:Object does not support the "css" property or method

who can help me? is the "this" problem? is have better function can do this?

Comment: Because elements are not actual objects in IE < 9. Anyway, your code is full of discouraged items (`eval`, `Object.prototype`). I recommend getting up-to-date with current best practices.

Comment: "full of discouraging aspects" +1 Don't use `eval()`, and I would not [attach a `.css()` method to every `object`](http://jsfiddle.net/c5yr3/).

Comment: Or arguably even worse: http://jsfiddle.net/c5yr3/1/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for [eval](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx), and there are other flaws in you code.
Try using something like:

```
function css(prop,value){
  value = value || '';

  if(prop) {
    this.style[prop] = value;
    return this.style[prop];
  }
  return true;
}

function $(ID){
  var element = document.getElementById(ID || 'nodId');

  if(element) {
    element.css = css; // create css method for this element
  }

  return element; // Note: element is null if no ID was provided
}

$("ad_ol").css("top","-170px"); //=> should work now
```

Comment: @Jared: yep, that's another possibility. There are many roads to Rome. In both cases, anyway, an error would be thrown if the element is not found.

Comment: @Jared: or http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/m7Fpg/, to prevent errors if element doesn't exist

Comment: @artwl - You'll need to provide more information. Note, you'll need to use Javascript `style` property syntax, ie, `border-style` is `borderStyle`, `font-style` is `fontStyle`, `background-color` is `backgroundColor`, etc. Omit the `-` and capitalize the first letter following where the `-` would be.

Comment: @Kooilnc this code can only set style property value,can't get style property value

Comment: @artwl - Resolved: http://jsfiddle.net/c5yr3/10/ (Note, I would refrain from using `$`, since so many other frameworks/libraries use it.)

Comment: @Jared, @artwl: `this.style[prop];` will only return a value if the property has been assigned previously. Otherwise you need something like: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle. Furthermore, you *can* set a dashed property, using bracket notation (like `element.style['border-color']`)

Comment: @artwl - Koolinc makes a good point (illustrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c5yr3/11/), note that `left` is set using selectors, but doesn't return a value). As far as `['border-style']`, I did not know that. `:)`

Comment: @artwl, @Jared: I have adjusted the jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/m7Fpg/) a bit, to demonstrate my comments. It includes `getComputedStyle/element.currentStyle' now